# XACML PolicySet and Request with example

Tags: wso2, rbac, xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I am new in XACML.I am planing to implement RBAC in our organization applications using XACML policy and Wso2 ID server. I had read many articles on creating different different XACML policy using wso2 and I also try many policy example.but after go through all the available example I didn't find proper way to creating XACML policyset and reuest for policy set. I try it by my self to create XACML PolicySet but when I try to execute this policyset in wso2 Id server then it gives me 'not applicable' error every time.I try a lot for creating XACML policyset in different way but when i create request for that then it not gives me proper result.
Help me to give proper example of XACML policyset and it's request.

Here I added my policyset and policy and also it's request. please let me know what was wrong in it.

Role Created in wso2Id is :- testRole
and assign this role to testUser

***PolicySet is :-***

```
<PolicySet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" PolicySetId="PolicySetExample" Version="1.0">
   <Description>TestPolicySet</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">H1</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:environment-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <PolicyIdReference>ComplexPolicy</PolicyIdReference>
</PolicySet>
```

***Policy***

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="ComplexPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">H1</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:environment-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="PermitForTestUser">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">index.jsp</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Apply>
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                     <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">view</AttributeValue>
                  </Apply>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">testRole</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
</Policy>
```

**PolicySet Request**

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">testU</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:environment-id" IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">H1</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">index.jsp</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Policy Set with WSO2IS,  Please note following.

1. You need to publish both Policy Set policy and reference policies in to PDP.
2. Then you need to enable the Policy Set in the PDP. You can keep the reference policies as disabled policies.

Please refer more detail from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/15/xacml-policy-set-with-identity-server/) as well

If you are going to implement RBAC and ABAC with WSO2 Identity Server, I recommnad for you to go through [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/30/implementing-rbac-and-abac-with-xacml/) to get more understanding.

Comment: The referenced sites are down now.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your policy using the Axiomatics Policy Server (see screenshot):

[image: The Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

I then tested the policy set using our simulator:

[image]

I received `Indeterminate` back as a response. The root cause of the `Indeterminate` is that your Condition inside the `Rule` has a flag called `MustBePresent` set to true on the `http://wso2.org/claims/role` attribute and that for some reason the evaluation did not retrieve any values.

[image: Simulation Result in the Axiomatics Policy Server]

It seems like the WSO2 IS is not retrieving the values for the role attribute. You want to check your configuration w/in WSO2 IS. Alternatively, test out the Axiomatics Policy Server.

HTH

Comment: Hello David, as you said " WSO2 IS is not retrieving the values for the role attribute" but in my wso2 logs it show me warning like this "{org.wso2.balana.PolicyReference} -  PolicyReference with id ComplexPolicy was queried but was not configured with a PolicyFinder
" but i already upload policy and policy set to policy finder. i don't know way this is not work. David can you please give me the example of PolicySet with policy reference inside policyset and policySet request with respect to Wso2 context??

Comment: It's work fine if i declare policy inside policy set. but if i pass reference of policy inside policy set then it's give me error like "Not Applicable" and in console it shows warning like mansion in above comment.